# Get id of the closest element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sitecore, sitecore-jss

Could anyone help to find out the way that i'm using for accessing the closest element `id` is right and if there is any issues by doing this. I'm using `sitecore headless` approach. So there is no way to send any props to child component by our own. If this approach is not a proper way is there any way to send **placeholder name** to the child component in sitecore. If that is possible there is no need of accessing DOM.

parent component

```
<div className={styles.xyz} id="xyz">
<Placeholder name='jss-content66' rendering={props.rendering}/>
</div>
```

Child Component

```
import {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
    import {LinkBoxDataConfig} from 'src/models/linkBox';
    import {formatLinkBoxData } from 'src/helpers/component.helper';
    import styles from './Linkbox.module.scss';
    
    export default function Linkbox (props: any) { 
    const linkData =  formatLinkBoxData(props);
    const nodeRef = useRef(null);
    
    useEffect (() => {
        const child = nodeRef.current; 
        if (child !== null) {
            const closest = child.parentNode.closest('div').id;
            console.log(closest)
        }
    },[]);
    return (
        <div
        className={styles.linkBox_container}
        ref={nodeRef}
        >
            {linkData && linkData.title && linkData.title !== '' ? (
                <div className={styles.linkBox_heading_container}>
                    <div className={styles.linkBox_heading}>{linkData.title} </div>
                </div>
            ):''
            }
        </div>
    );
    }
```

Comment: Where is the id even located? Is it a `data-` property on the parent? I don't see it anywhere in the code.

Comment: @IP002 its a normal id attribute in parent div ex : id="xyz"

Comment: What's wrong with what you currently have? It looks like it should function. On the other hand, directly interacting with the DOM in React is often a sign you're doing something unusual. Why do you need this `id`?

Comment: It might help us if you explained what it is you are trying to do. Why, for example, do you need a ref, and why do you need its closest div? There maybe a more appropriate solution.

Comment: @DBS i need the id because based on that i need to switch the classname in child component . But here the issue is that i cannot pass that via props. To be more specific i'm using sitecore headless approach. Here components are rendering based on an api data. Thats why i cannot send this data via props.

Comment: OK so you're getting data from the CMS via API and passing that to `LinkBox`? Is there a reason you can't just update the component interface to accept one more prop? Maybe I'm not understanding how Sitecore works. Anyway: what you should do is update your question with _all_ the relevant details (ie including the sitecore stuff, and the parent component that renders `LinkBox`). @soorajspillai.

Comment: @Andy you're correct i'm getting api from CMS and passing that to LinkBox and due to dynamic rendering of components we've no way to pass one more prop. I'll update the question with more data.

Comment: I can't even read your first sentence.